# Tools to optimize logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

I am writing a processor simulator in java, and the control signals are beyond cumbersome. Are there any tools that generates logics as below:

binary logic(s):

```
input[0]: 00001
input[1]: 00000
input[2]: 00010
input[3]: 00011
```

output:

```
if(input.subString(0,3) == "000") 
    //do something;
```

Basically the output find the common parts of the input. in the example above, it's saying "Anything starting with 000 will do something", regardless of whether its `00000, 00001,  00010, 00011`

The optimization is similar to a k-map, except I have a hundred input, and optimize by hand is simply not practical.

Here is an example of k-map, **not related to my example above**

[image: example kmap]

The output doesn't have to be in java syntax, any simplified logic statement will do

Comment: So if I want to post a question asking for help understanding this question, does it go on stackoverflow or on meta?

Comment: If you need clarification from me, you can just post in the comments.. but if you are seeking help from others, i believe it goes to meta.

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to be funny.  I have no idea what you are trying to say and I think you need to explain in more detail what do you mean by generating logic.

Comment: hah gotcha, let me add more explanation then

Answer (score 1):

So you've got a big set of strings of length `N` bits (where `N` is approximately 100), and you want a simple logic expression that matches those strings and none others?

You could try to make a program that builds the Kernaugh map for you.  It would be an interesting exercise.  I don't remember much about Kernaugh maps, but I think the labels on rows and columns arranged using a Gray code.

Or you could just try to make the problem more tractable for hand-made Kernaugh maps.  For each of the strings, find the bits that are common to all of them.  Then print a list of the remaining bit positions for the human to build a map of.

A bit of Python code:

```
str_len = 5
strs = [
     [0,0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1],
]
for i in range(str_len):
    if all([x[i] for x in strs]):
        print 'Bit %d is 1' % i
    elif not any([x[i] for x in strs]):
        print 'Bit %d is 0' % i
    else:
        print 'Bit %d is contingent' % i
```

At that point you could try to think of ways to encode the `B` remaining contingent bits.  In this example, it so happens that all cases are covered (and you could detect that as a special case -- e.g. `N = 2^B`).

A brute force algorithm for finding a formula for the contingent bits would be:

1. Pick the next contingent bit `i`.
2. Divide S into S0 (the subset where bit `i` = 0) and S1 (the subset where bit `i` = 1).
3. Recursively find the formulas f0 and f1 for S0 and S1 respectively.
4. The formula for S is `(~b[i] & f0) | (b[i] & f1)`.

There are some optimisations.  The easy one is where S0 or S1 is empty -- then just omit that branch of the resulting formula.  Another one is where all possible combinations are in a set (similar to the example above); the formula doesn't need to refer to the bits in that case.  The hardest one is finding a good order to iterative over the bits in.  Doing it naively in order may result in a less-than-optimal formula.

You could in fact skip the first suggestion above and run this over all bits.  Bits which are always 1 or 0 would simply yield trivial cases where S0 or S1 is empty.

This rather messy Python code performs the algorithm with a few optimisations.  **N.B.** It's not tested much and doesn't necessarily produce optimal output!

```
def get_formula(S, i=0):
    # Special case where it's an empty set -- return a tautology
    if len(S) == 0:
        return '1'

    remaining_bits = len(S[0]) - i

    # Special case where no bits are left
    if remaining_bits <= 0:
        return '1'

    # Partition the set
    S0 = filter(lambda x: x[i] == 0, S)
    S1 = filter(lambda x: x[i] == 1, S)

    f0 = get_formula(S0, i+1)
    f1 = get_formula(S1, i+1)

    # Special cases where one subset is empty
    # Also special case for subformula being tautology
    if len(S1) == 0:
        if f0 == '1':
            return '~b[%d]' % i
        return '~b[%d] & (%s)' % (i, f0)
    if len(S0) == 0:
        if f1 == '1':
            return 'b[%d]' % i
        return 'b[%d] & (%s)' % (i, f1)

    # Special cases where one or both subformulas was a tautology
    if f0 == '1' and f1 == '1':
        return '1'
    if f0 == '1':
        return '~b[%d] | b[%d] & (%s)' % (i, i, f1)
    if f1 == '1':
        return '~b[%d] & (%s) | b[%d]' % (i, f0, 1)

    # General case
    return '~b[%d] & (%s) | b[%d] & (%s)' % (i, f0, i, f1)


strs = [
     [0,0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1],
]

print get_formula(strs)
```

Finally, I think one way to make this code find more optimal formulas would be to scan ahead in `S` for bits that are always 0 or always 1, and process them early.  The remaining continginent bits in each subset will get pushed into the deeply-nested subformulas where they will form less redundant formulas than when they are processed too early.  I think this will in effect simulate a Kernaugh-map style construction: at each step, the set of always 0 or always 1 bits defines a rectangle on the map.  Find that set, process them all at once (e.g. as a compact formula `~b[0] & ~b[1] & ~b[2]`) then recurse on the remaining bits.  You need to keep track of which bit positions have already been processed, rather than doing them in order using `i`.

(Actually, now that I think about it, for optimal formulas you also need to partition smartly by selecting a bunch of correlated bits at a time.  An interesting problem...)